# Python ctypes not working with Structures

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

I need to use some code from `LabVIEW` in `Python`. `LabVIEW` code is used as `DLL`. So, I'm using `ctypes` library in Python. In one case, I need to pass `cluster`s from Python to LabVIEW. I'm facing issues in passing clusters.

The problem is with particular ordering of elements inside the LabVIEW cluster(I am aware that clusters strictly follow ordering). My cluster has a `double` value and an `integer array`. When the double is the first element in the cluster things work well. But when the array is set as the first element and double as the second element, things don't work at all. I'm using LabVIEW 2015(32-bit) and Python 3(32-bit).

I suspect `ctypes` to be the cause for the issue. Because, the same DLL is working as expected in `C` and in `LabVIEW`. I have also tried using the DLL in LabVIEW which is working fine.

I have narrowed down this issue to the following example. The DLL in this example has 2 functions. Each function uses a cluster. `Func1` uses `cluster1` which is `array` followed by a `double`. While `Func2` uses `cluster` which is `double` followed by `array`. 
Both these functions receive a `cluster` as input and just return the `double` value(as it is from the input cluster) as output.

Find those information in the header file.

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t dimSize;
    uint64_t elt[1];
} Uint64ArrayBase;
typedef Uint64ArrayBase **Uint64Array;
typedef struct {
    double Double;
    Uint64Array _1DArray;
} Cluster;
typedef struct {
    Uint64Array _1DArray;
    double Double;
} Cluster1;

/*!
 * Func2
 */
double __cdecl Func2(Cluster *Double1DArrayCluster);
/*!
 * Func1
 */
double __cdecl Func1(Cluster1 *_1DArrayDoubleCluster);

MgErr __cdecl LVDLLStatus(char *errStr, int errStrLen, void *module);

/*
* Memory Allocation/Resize/Deallocation APIs for type 'Uint64Array'
*/
Uint64Array __cdecl AllocateUint64Array (int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl ResizeUint64Array (Uint64Array *hdlPtr, int32 elmtCount);
MgErr __cdecl DeAllocateUint64Array (Uint64Array *hdlPtr);
```

This is my python code.

```py
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("DLL.dll")
dbl = 45.54
elt_count = 5

class Uint64ArrayBase(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dimSize", c_int32),
        ("elt", c_uint64 * elt_count)
    ]

class Cluster(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("Double", c_double),
        ("_1DArray", POINTER(POINTER(Uint64ArrayBase)))
    ]

class Cluster1(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("_1DArray", POINTER(POINTER(Uint64ArrayBase))),
        ("Double", c_double)
    ]

Uint64Array = POINTER(POINTER(Uint64ArrayBase))

# Use the given API to allocate array
lib.AllocateUint64Array.restype = Uint64Array
lib.AllocateUint64Array.argtypes = [c_int32]
uintarr_h = lib.AllocateUint64Array(c_int32(elt_count))

# Populate the elts of the array
for i in range(elt_count):
    uintarr_h.contents.contents.elt[i] = c_uint64(i)

# Create cluster instances
dbl_arr_cluster = Cluster(c_double(dbl), uintarr_h)
arr_dbl_cluster = Cluster1(uintarr_h, c_double(dbl))

# Print the array for Debugging
print("Array from arr_dbl_cluster:", end=" ")
for i in range(arr_dbl_cluster._1DArray.contents.contents.dimSize):
    print(arr_dbl_cluster._1DArray.contents.contents.elt[i], end=", ")
print()

print("Array from dbl_arr_cluster:", end=" ")
for i in range(dbl_arr_cluster._1DArray.contents.contents.dimSize):
    print(dbl_arr_cluster._1DArray.contents.contents.elt[i], end=", ")
print()

print("Double from arr_dbl_cluster:", arr_dbl_cluster.Double)
print("Double from dbl_arr_cluster:", dbl_arr_cluster.Double)

# Test the funcs
lib.Func1.restype = c_double
lib.Func1.argtypes = [POINTER(Cluster1)]
lib.Func2.restype = c_double
lib.Func2.argtypes = [POINTER(Cluster)]

print()

result = lib.Func1(byref(arr_dbl_cluster))
print("Double output from DLL function cluster{Array, DBL}:", result)
result_1 = lib.Func2(byref(dbl_arr_cluster))
print("Double output from DLL function cluster{DBL, Array}:", result_1)
```

Also, the `C` code.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "DLL.h"

int main() {
    double dbl = 45.54, result, result1;
    int32 eltCount = 5, i;

    // Use the API to allocate array
    Uint64Array uia = AllocateUint64Array(eltCount);

    // Populate the elts of the array
    for (i = 0; i < (*uia)->dimSize; i++) {
        (*uia)->elt[i] = (int)i;
    }

    // Create cluster instances
    Cluster cluster = { dbl, uia };
    Cluster1 cluster1 = { uia, dbl };

    // Print for Debugging
    printf("\nArray from cluster1{Array, DBL}: ");
    for (i = 0; i < (*cluster1._1DArray)->dimSize; i++) {
        printf("%llu, ", (*cluster1._1DArray)->elt[i]);
    }
    printf("\nArray from cluster{DBL, Array}: ");
    for (i = 0; i < (*cluster._1DArray)->dimSize; i++) {
        printf("%llu, ", (*cluster._1DArray)->elt[i]);
    }

    printf("\nDouble from cluster1{Array, DBL}: %lf", cluster1.Double);
    printf("\nDouble from cluster{DBL, Array}: %lf", cluster.Double);

    // Test the funcs
    result = Func1(&cluster1);
    result1 = Func2(&cluster);
    printf("\n\nDouble output from DLL function cluster1{Array, DBL}: %lf", result);
    printf("\nDouble output from DLL function cluster{DBL, Array}: %lf", result1);

    return 0;
}
```

The following is the output from `Python` which is not expected. `45.54` must have been returned as output by both the functions.

```
c:/Users/samkm/Desktop/DLL Demo/test.py
Array from arr_dbl_cluster: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
Array from dbl_arr_cluster: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
Double from arr_dbl_cluster: 45.54
Double from dbl_arr_cluster: 45.54

Double output from DLL function cluster{Array, DBL}: -2.106485661434095e-37  # int(...) -> 0
Double output from DLL function cluster{DBL, Array}: 45.54
```

And the `C` code returns the expected output.

```
Array from cluster1{Array, DBL}: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
Array from cluster{DBL, Array}: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
Double from cluster1{Array, DBL}: 45.540000
Double from cluster{DBL, Array}: 45.540000

Double output from DLL function cluster1{Array, DBL}: 45.540000
Double output from DLL function cluster{DBL, Array}: 45.540000
```

[image: LabVIEW code for Func1]
LabVIEW code for func1

[image: LabVIEW code for Func2]
LabVIEW code for func2

Has anyone faced this issue? What should be done in this case?

Comment: I recommend removing the "LabVIEW" tag from this post. The details of how the DLL came into being are irrelevant (since you know it works in other contexts). You need Python -> C experts, not LabVIEW -> Python experts. I suspect removing the LabVIEW tags will get more eyes on this, and thus more help.

Comment: Is the *.dll* that you're using from *LabVIEW* or it was created by you (or a 3rd-party)? Also you are using *Yython 3* (*64bit*) on *Win*?

Comment: Also, what does `print(arr_dbl_cluster.Double, dbl_arr_cluster.Double)` output? Please post all relevant code as described in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @CristiFati I have created the .dll from LabVIEW(32-bit). I'm using Python(32-bit) on Windows 10. Also `print(arr_dbl_cluster.Double, dbl_arr_cluster.Double)` gives proper values: 45.54, 45.54. Do you need any other code? All needed code are posted here. Let me Know.

Comment: How about for *Func1*, *Func2*, and *AllocateUint64Array *?

Comment: @CristiFati Func1, Func2 and AllocateUint64Array are coded in LabVIEW. So, they are diagrams. I'll try sharing those images in sometime. As mentioned above, Func1 and Func2 are very simple functions which just accept a cluster as input; reads them; returns the Double value as output. But, "AllocateUint64Array" is an API provided by LabVIEW; so I don't have the code for it. It's abstracted.

Comment: Hmm, I see. How do you know that the 2 functions are so simple since you didn't see their implementation? Have you tried reproducing the problem with a dummy *.dll* that only contains the 3 functions written by you (based on the feeling of what their *LabVIEW* generated implementations are)? Because if each one of the 2 would be simply e.g. `return Double1DArrayCluster->Double;`, this error wouldn't be encountered.

Comment: @CristiFati Func1 and Func2 are written by Me. I have shared the code snippets above. While the "AllocateUint64Array" is an API - I don't have any idea about it except understanding from the Header file that it creates memory and returns a handle.

Comment: I have tried a dummy .dll coded in C++. It's works well in Python.

Comment: `Uint64ArrayBase.elt` definition differs in *C* (*uint64_t* - ***8*** bytes) and *Python* (*c\_uint* - ***4*** bytes). It should be *c\_uint64*. Not sure if this will fix the issue since *Cluster* contains a (double) pointer to it.

Comment: Changing it to c_uint64 didn't help

Comment: You should get somehow the *C* code generated by *LabVIEW* for those functions (http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/373192a.pdf) - and used to build the *.dll*, and paste it here.